# Preview render view is noisy, not sure what I did or how to fix it

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

So when I'm in render preview it looks like this:

[image] which is odd because the render looks fine

[image]

I can only assume that I messed up some sort of display or view, other .blend files aren't affected. Does anybody see something familiar and know how to fix this?

Comment: Preview samples are only at 6, which is quite low, could be the cause for the artifacts. Try increasing the preview number of samples under the Render Settings > Sampling > Preview

Comment: but keep in mind that previews are just... previews. if your preview has same settings as final renders, you'll spend so much time in previews... you can do any way you want, of course, but to just check how it wil render finally, there's also the "render border" option, just in case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As m.ardito says, "previews are just... previews"

Unless you set your preview sample value to something very high, you wont get good results like the final render. In fact, that is why it is called a preview. The point of a preview is to render the file fast so you can look at how it will change in the final render. In preview mode it is easier to make materials and change lights.

If you want a higher quality preview image, just increase the samples under "preview." But, be warned, setting the sample size to something higher takes much longer to preview.

Comment: Changing render preview changed nothing unfortunately(even at 500 preview it was still jagged), but since this problem was only affecting this one *.blend file I just append all the objects to a new project and saved over the original.